# Creating MS Outlook Email Template with Attachments (error msg)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, templates

I have created one email template (with attachments) that works fine. I am accessing it from my QAT from a macro button. However, I cannot duplicate the process again to create a new template or edit the existing one. I keep getting the error message “The attempted operation failed. An object cannot be found”. I don’t think anything needs to be updated as my first template with attachments is working fine. I am not sure what I am missing! Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

How do you create the template? check [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-email-message-template-43ec7142-4dd0-4351-8727-bd0977b6b2d1) about official steps.

Test this issue in [a new profile](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-Outlook-profile-f544c1ba-3352-4b3b-be0b-8d42a540459d)